# How does an inner product $V \times V \to F$ induce a vector norm $V \to \mathbb{R}?$

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $\mathbb{F}=\left(F,+_F,\cdot_F\right)$ be a field and $\mathbb{V}=\left(V,\mathbb{F},+,\cdot\right)$ be a vector space. Let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle : V \times V \to F$ be an inner product. If $F \neq \mathbb{R},$ then how can we say that the $\left\Vert x \right\Vert = \sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}$ is a valid vector norm$?$ Because a vector norm is a map $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert : V \to \mathbb{R}$.

Should we modify the definition of the induced norm to be $\left\Vert x \right\Vert = \sqrt{\left|\langle x,x \rangle\right|},$ where
$\left|\cdot\right| : F \to \mathbb{R}$ is a pre-fixed norm$?$

Comment: Usually the field $\Bbb F$ is taken to be a subfield of $\Bbb C$ when talking about inner product.

Comment: Talking about a norm doesn't even make sense unless $F \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Recall the rule that $\| \lambda v \| = |\lambda| * \| v \|$ for scalars $\lambda \in F$.

Comment: @AJY It's not necessary to have $F\subseteq\mathbb{C}$. Any "valued" field with "valuation" (a.k.a. absolute value) is sufficient. But to have an inner product, the field in question must be a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ indeed.

Comment: @AJY In fact, it is possible to make sense of a "norm" with $\Bbb F \not\subset \Bbb C$, at least in some circumstances. For instance, with $\Bbb F$ equal to the $p$-adics, we can make sense of the norm property by interpreting $|\lambda|$ as the [$p$-adic absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who say that "an inner product induces a norm" define the term "inner product" to apply specifically to the case in which $\Bbb F \in \{\Bbb R,\Bbb C\}$.  In those cases, the definition $\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$ is perfectly fine.

With this convention, a bilinear map $V \times V \to \Bbb F$ would be called a "scalar product" or a "bilinear form" as opposed to an "inner product".

Comment: That's helpful. Just a little problem when $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C},$ in that case by $\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle},$ do you mean $\|x\| = \sqrt{\left|\langle x, x \rangle\right|}?$

Comment: @pkxop You do not need the extra absolute value because the inner product of $x$ with itself is assumed to be real and nonnegative.

Comment: @pkxop I do not.  Typically, an inner product over $\Bbb C$ is defined to be a conjugate-linear inner product (rather than a bilinear form).  As such, we necessarily have $\langle x,x\rangle \in \Bbb R$, and the positive-deifniteness of an inner product ensures that $\langle x,x \rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)

> There are various technical reasons why it is necessary to restrict the basefield to R and C in the definition. Briefly, the basefield has to contain an ordered subfield in order for non-negativity to make sense,[4] and therefore has to have characteristic equal to 0 (since any ordered field has to have such characteristic). This immediately excludes finite fields. The basefield has to have additional structure, such as a distinguished automorphism. More generally any quadratically closed subfield of R or C will suffice for this purpose, e.g., the algebraic numbers or the constructible numbers. However in these cases when it is a proper subfield (i.e., neither R nor C) even finite-dimensional inner product spaces will fail to be metrically complete. In contrast all finite-dimensional inner product spaces over R or C, such as those used in quantum computation, are automatically metrically complete and hence Hilbert spaces.